# How do I convert a string of numbers to an integer array?

Tags: java, arrays, string, char, integer

I have a string like, `"12345"` and want to convert it to the integer array, `{1,2,3,4,5}`.

I want one method to convert a character to an integer, `'1' -> 1`. And another method to create the array.

This is what I have so far:

```java
public static int charToInt(char character) {
    int newInt;

    newInt = (int) character;

    return newInt;
}

public static int[] convertStringToIntArray(String keyString) {
    int keyLength = keyString.length();
    int element;

    int[] intArray = new int[keyLength];

    for (element = 0; element < keyLength; element++) {
        intArray[element] = charToInt(keyString.charAt(element));
    }

    // return
    return intArray;
}
```

I think the problem is in the `charToInt` method. I think it is converting the `char` to its *ascii* value. But I am not sure if the other method is right either.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right. The problem here is in `charToInt`.
`(int) character` is just the ascii codepoint (or rather UTF-16 codepoint).

Because the digits `'0'` to `'9'` have increasing codepoints you can convert any digit into a number by subtracting `'0'`.

```
public static int charToInt(char digit)
{
   return digit - '0';
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Since Java 1.5 `Character` has an interesting method [`getNumericValue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#getNumericValue(int)) which allows to convert char digits to int values.

So with the help of Stream API, the entire method `convertStringToIntArray` may be rewritten as:

```java
public static int[] convertStringToIntArray(String keyString) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(keyString);
    return keyString.chars().map(Character::getNumericValue).toArray();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This might help -

```
int keyLength = keyString.length();
int num = Integer.parseInt(keyString);
int[] intArray = new int[ keyLength ];

for(int i=keyLength-1; i>=0; i--){
    intArray[i] = num % 10;
    num = num / 10;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since *Java 9* you can use [`String#codePoints`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#codePoints--) method.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY8/a8MwEMV3f4ojk1yoQv8tMR1KpwwphZYupcNVFq4cWzKnk8GUfHb3EhunQ3uLxDveu9@rscfLutyPo2u7QAy1CDqxa/RFkWVd@mycAdNgjLBD5@E7A5lZj4wsj/P8/gEm@N4SvzA5X72GrecHIhzUJMDeDtMvnzOOQ5YT@fNOm1Da5yCBUeW6xU49fiGhYUubTWX5KbWWnHnDJtlcc5gu5MUp8JD9wdYHV0Ir5DOHgCJV8TfEDBiZ4B5WV9c3t3erYtlO5ZCOy/8qilUYFst6DSFxl/h8YohsWy2q7sTLjVcnZ5QOU5qSC/lS5DCOPw)

```java
public static int[] convertStringToIntArray(String keyString) {
    return keyString.codePoints().map(Character::getNumericValue).toArray();
}
```

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "12345";
    int[] arr = convertStringToIntArray(str);

    // output
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
    // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
}
```